# Referencing a "partition table" foreign key in Multi-Tenant Code-First Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, multi-tenant

I am creating a multi-tenant application that needs to be built in a single database. To partition the tables, we have a `Tenant` entity whose primary key will be referenced as part of the keys of other tables that need partitioning. The `Tenant` entity looks like this:

```
public class Tenant
{
    [Key]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    public string TenantName { get; set; }
}
```

An example of where this partitioning is used is in a `Store`-`Item` scenario, where a tenant can have multiple stores as well as multiple items. Stores can have multiple items, and their relationships are maintained in a `StoreItem` entity. Our current implementation looks like this:

**Store Entity**

```
public class Store
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string StoreId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

**Item Entity**

```
public class Item
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

**StoreItem Entity**

```
public class StoreItem
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string StoreId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public string ItemId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StoreId")]
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

When we try to build the database, I encounter the ff. error:

> StoreItem_Item_Target_StoreItem_Item_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.
>
> StoreItem_Store_Target_StoreItem_Store_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

What is wrong with the way I structured my keys? Should `TenantId` not be referenced as part of the Key for other entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `[ForeignKey("ItemId")]` to describe part of the relationship between `StoreItem` and `Item` but `Item` has multiple key columns. If you need the `TenantId` to be part of the key -- which you shouldn't if `ItemId` is enough to uniquely identify an `Item` record -- then I think you'd need to use the fluent API to define the relationship.

On the other hand, I'm guessing you don't need `TenantId` as a key column for either `Item` or `Store`, which would simplify things greatly.

Comment: I had to rework some of my designs, but I agree with your answer. I was just holding on to hope that partitioning with a TenantId would allow me to duplicate some other ID columns in the table.